# Put Data into Columns of CSV based on what list it is in - Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv

I have two lists that exist in my script - vulnsites and notvulnsites, which hold a list of sites identified to contain a vulnerability. I would like to write these out to two separate columns of a CSV - Vulnerable Sites and False Positives. I have the following code,  currently:

```
    with open (outputfile, 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    fields = ['Vulnerable Sites', 'False Positives']
    writer.writerows([fields])

    for val in vulnsites:
        writer.writerow([val])

    for val in notvulnsites:
        writer.writerow([val]])
```

Presently, the fields are created as A1 and B1 in Excel. When I write the data, all sites are dumped into the 'A' column of Excel, regardless of what list they are in. How can I correct this?

Edit: Basing on Daniel's recommendation of using Panda's DataFrames and his help doing so, I came up with the following code to solve this issue:

```
CSVOut = {'Vulnerable Sites':vulnsites,'False Positives':notvulnsites}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(CSVOut, orient='index')
df.to_csv(outputfile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two lists called `vulnsites` and `notvulnsites` and want to dump them into a csv file?

This accounts for possible different lengths of the two strings:

```
import pandas as pd
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'vulnerable':vulnsites})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'not_vulnerable':notvulnsites})
df = pd.concat([df_a,df_b],axis=1)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Two-liner version, less readable but equivalent:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'vulnerable':vulnsites}),pd.DataFrame({'not_vulnerable':notvulnsites})],axis=1).to_csv('data.csv')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution requires all lists to be the same length, and given the context, that's not predictable. I'll play with this to see if I can make it work.

Comment: Updated, this accounts for differences in sizes

Comment: I ended up going with a different solution, which I will edit my post with, but I'm marking this best answer as it answered the question 99% of the way!

Comment: I will edit the answer then so as to show only the definitive solution.

Comment: Then csv is not the format of choice for you. The idea of csv is that each line consists of several values,  which share the same description or type per column. For example, if the list of false positives is a subset of vulnerable sites, then you could write two columns in the file: one is perhaps URL and the other ISFALSEPOS, where you just list boolean values True and False. Then your columns would be equally long by definition and that's data where csv would suit.

Comment: @SpghttCd True. The question did not describe the reason why the file was created; but for all practical purposes, as you suggest, he would want to have a column with the identification of the website, and a column with a boolean corresponding to the feature of interest.